# Massive amount of data being generated somewhere, filling up disk space

Tags: partitioning, storage, logs

Preface: I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I can provide additional information if requested.

Somehow, some way my disk is filling up hundreds of gigabytes of empty space in just a few hours entirely on its own. Disk analyzer shows root directory has approximately 170 gigabytes of data in it. My hard drive is 1 TB. I see no other files that could occupy the other 800 gigabytes but i am being told that there is less than 1 GB remaining when I look at the disk in file manager. I did remove some massive log files totaling 500 GB earlier but I do not see anything that replaced them. These warnings and problems appeared today. I have no idea what changed.

Comment: If you remove/delete a in-use file, the inodes used by that file won't become available until the task/process using it has finished. Whilst I don't understand your issue (have you worked out the files using the space, `du` etc), were the 500gb of logs you deleted in-use? (thus inodes haven't become available yet? as we cannot know given we don't know what logs they were).

Comment: clean logs : `sudo /etc/cron.daily/logrotate; sudo find /var/log -type f -iname *.gz -delete`

Comment: @cmak.fr Discarding uninspected log files will lead to unresolved problems. Log files have been my friend for over 50 years in the business. Readingt the logs to diagnose the problem, and fixing the problem, THEN deleting logs is the way to go, IMHO.

Comment: @waltinator : my comment was not an answer but some complementary  information related to previous comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can see large, open files with

```
sudo lsof / | \
awk '{if(\$7 > 1048576) print \$7/1048576 \"MB\" \" \" \$9 }' | \
sort -n -u
```

(Change `1048576` (1GB) to a smaller number to see other files).

To see open, deleted files,

```
sudo lsof / | egrep 'PID|\(deleted\)'
```

Comment: too much backslashes to me...

Comment: `awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ backslash not last character on line`